# Expand dropdown menu if one of the sub-menu items is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu which is expanded by clicking. The menu is collapsed by default. I would like the menu to appear to be expanded if one of the sub menu pages is active. I hope that's clear. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a class="disablelink" href="#">Carbohydrates, proteins &amp; fats</a>
            <ul class="sub_navigation">
                <li><a href="carbohydrates.php">Carbohydrates</a></li>
                <li><a href="proteins.php">Proteins</a></li>
                <li><a href="fats.php">Fats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown').click(function() {
                        // When the event is triggered, grab the current element 'this' and
                        // find it's children '.sub_navigation' and display/hide them
            $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle(); 
        });

        $(".disablelink").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

So if the user is on `carbohydrates.php`, `proteins.php` or  `fats.php` i would like the menu to be expanded. I don't know how to do this though. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a page is active you would need to give it's link an additional class, for example;

`<li class="current_page"><a href="carbohydrates.php">Carbohydrates</a></li>`.

Then you can use jQuery to loop through the menu and expand it if any menu item have the class.

```
$('.dropdown li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('current_page')) {
           $(this).closest('.sub_navigation').slideDown();          
    }            
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R7gkw/

Comment: Thanks for the response. It appears, however, that the menu is always expanded no matter what page i'm on

Comment: It will always be expanded if there is a list item this that class. If you remove it you will see that it doesn't expand. You would need to add this class using PHP (Or which ever language you are using).

Comment: Well i'm using php mostly. I know that `substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);` will give me the current relative url but i wouldn't know how to go about looping through the dropdown menu links to check if the href matches the current url

Comment: If you know the relative url (matches the value in the links href exactly) you can just use a simple if statement; `class=" <?php if( $url == 'carbohydrates.php' ) echo 'current_page'; ?> "`. [This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/keepingcurrent/) might also be helpful. Also you might also be able to do this with jQuery using [something like this](http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-jquery-to-highlight-active-menu-item).

Comment: I was looking for a more generic way to do it, rather than hard-coding specific url. I've done it now with jQuery and decided not to do it with PHP.